# If statement seems to run some code but not all in java

Tags: java

I'm making a 2d platformer in libgdx with box2d. The below is the update method for one of my enemies. It's an extension of the 'Enemy' class, which is what 'super.update' refers to. I want the enemy to run when the player is behind it or far away and to stop and shoot when the player is close to it and in front of it.

I try to achieve this by setting the speed (velocity.x) initially [depending on the enemy's direction], then setting whether or not it's shooting afterwards.

The problem I have at the moment is that the enemy doesn't run when the player is behind it. As you can see, I printed out a lot of strings to console to see when the velocity.x gets changed back to 0. According to the console, it happens in the last if/else pair of statements which are supposed to check how far away the player is and which direction the enemy is running. However, the console strings within those statements, the ones that say 'Shoot Left' or 'Shoot Right', don't get printed out. Despite this, the line that changes velocity.x must get run because the it's value changes according to the string output in the next line. The if statements at the top which check direction must get run as well because the console outputs within those statements get printed, and the output that says the velocity says the correct velocity (either 2 or -2).

What is going on? It seems like the IDE is running only one of the lines in the if statement. That's impossible so what am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

```
public void update (float dt, Player player){
    super.update(dt, player);
    if (b2body.isActive()){
        System.out.println(b2body.getPosition().x - player.b2body.getPosition().x);
        System.out.println("After Enemy code: " + velocity.x);
        if (getRunningRight()) {
            System.out.println("Right");
            velocity.x = 2;
        }
        else if (!getRunningRight()) {
            System.out.println("Left");
            velocity.x = -2; 
        }
        System.out.println("After checking direction: " + velocity.x);

        if ((b2body.getPosition().x - player.b2body.getPosition().x <= 2 &&
                b2body.getPosition().x - player.b2body.getPosition().x >= 0) && !getRunningRight()){
            velocity.x = 0;
            System.out.println("Shoot left");
        }
        else if ((b2body.getPosition().x - player.b2body.getPosition().x >= -2 &&
                b2body.getPosition().x - player.b2body.getPosition().x < 0) && getRunningRight()){
            System.out.println("Shoot right");
            velocity.x = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("After shooting: " + velocity.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: The way to debug code is through the debugger. Printing stuff can help under certain circumstances, but it sounds like what you really need here is line-by-line stepping.

Comment: maybe clarify your question a little bit. Your long paragraph confuses people

Comment: I bet velocity.x is modified inside the if() statements, i.e. somewhere in the methods that are called in the if conditions (`b2body.getPosition()` `getRunningRight()`). I'd check those for side effects.

Comment: Maybe 'getRunningRight()' evaluates to a different value in the bottom if blocks than in the top ones. Call it once and use that value in all if blocks.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @FeinesFabi This seems to have been the problem, yes. I called getRunningRight only once, assigned it to a variable and used that as the check for which the enemy was running, and it works as intended now. Do you know what is happening there? I don't understand

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks for the comment, the reason I couldn't use the debugger is because I need to get to be behind the enemy, so either jump over it to the other side, or else move far enough away that it will run, hit a wall and turn around. But the only places I can set a breakpoint will just keep repeating every frame.

Comment: Without seeing the code of 'getRunningRight()' it's really hard to tell. I'd bet it's a timing issue where code is executed in a different order then you think. Or the method performs some mutation (side effects) that you didn't expect.

Comment: But why would only some of the code get executed? the code of getRunningRight() is: {if (b2body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0) runningRight = false;
  else if (b2body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0) runningRight = true;
  return runningRight;} Sorry about the formatting. The idea is that if the sprite doesn't move, the method will return the previous runningRight.

Comment: @foopydoop Then it sounds like you're ready to graduate to "conditional breakpoints" (for which see your debugger documentation). They'll let you continue executing until a condition of your choosing evaluates to true.

Comment: @Sneftel I'll look into it for next time, but what condition could I put? Finding a condition that would reliably execute when I was behind the enemy is exactly the problem I was having. Maybe when I press a button?

Answer (score 3):

In your first set of `if`s, you evaluate `getRunningRight()` after you have already determined that it will be false (by the initial `if` failing), so there is no need to evaluate it again.

If you think you are doing the same thing in the second block, you are not; the expression in the inner `if` is not the opposite of the first one.  That is, *(A && B) && C* is not the opposite of *(!A && !B) && !C*.  Thus, it is possible for both expressions to be false.